# OCR by Python from a tutorial doesn't work

Tags: python, ocr

I am trying to do some OCR with Python using [this tutorial](http://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/11/ocr-python-easy/). However - all I'm getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\111", line 6, in <module>
    text = image_to_string(im)
  File "D:\Programming\Python26\lib\site-packages\pytesser.py", line 31, in image_to_string
    call_tesseract(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
  File "D:\Programming\Python26\lib\site-packages\pytesser.py", line 21, in call_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
  File "D:\Programming\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "D:\Programming\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 821, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2]
```

What does this mean and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That error suggests that windows can't find the file specified

Comment: WindowsError 2 is ile not found. It can't find the Tesseract executable. Is it in your PATH?

Comment: I have added D:\Programming\Tesseract-OCR\ to my Path variable, Python gives me the same error :-(

Comment: Oopps - apparently I needed to restart Python for the changes to take effect - thanks a lot guys!!!

Comment: I can't seem to find how to pick the best answer...